# What does my Visual Studio 2010 toolbar button do?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've added some custom toolbar buttons to Visual Studio that call macros--some I've written, and some that are Microsoft's.

Some of the buttons have been there a while, and I've forgotten just exactly what they do. So, for a custom button that already exists on my toolbar (that I've added in the past), how can I determine what macro (or command, or whatever) it is calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [VSCT Power Toy](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VSCTPowerToy) to find out.